# How do I use table type as input to a function in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am using

1. PostgreSQL 13
2. pgAdmin 4 to execute the sql file (I thought this is relevant as errors in sql files weirdly seem to be dependent on where it is run from (at least on the default settings of those programs). Any tips on this might also be helpful)

I am trying to define a function that takes a table as input and also outputs a table. But there is a syntax error here saying:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE"
LINE 77: CREATE TYPE DirectoryIdTableType AS TABLE (id BIGINT);
```

It seems postgresql does not allow a table type. Putting `TABLE` as the data type in the arguments also does not work. So, how do I solve this?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
SET search_path TO Schema1;

CREATE TYPE DirectoryIdTableType AS TABLE (id BIGINT);

CREATE FUNCTION f(_userId BIGINT, _directoryIdTable DirectoryIdTableType)
RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT, n int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    -- a complex select statement --
$$;
```

Comment: See answer https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/141766

Comment: Where in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) did you find the `as table` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "table type" in PostgreSQL. Possible ways to do what you want.can be:

- Pass the input as an array of records. This will run into memory problems for bigger tables, because the array is kept in memory.
- Create a temporary table with your input data, pass its name to the function and access it with dynamic SQL inside the function.
- Create a cursor for a query that returns the input table and pass it as a `refcursor` argument to the function. Fetch from the cursor inside the function.